# Keycloak/angular-oauth2-oidc invalid nonce issue

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have a basic angular-oauth2-oidc + Keycloak integration. The authentication is done through the auth code + PKSE flow, which works correctly.

The issue I have is in the Keycloak forgot password and email verificaiton emails. Let's take the forgot password flow :

- The user clicks on sign in to be redirected to the Keycloak login page.
- The user clicks on forgot password.
- The user receives an email with the reset password link
- The user enters a new password and is redirected back to the angular application (not keycloak).(From the network calls, I see that the user is logged in keycloak and redirected back to the angular app so it can retrieve the access token)

This seems to be also the default behavior of Keycloak as the reset password form returns a 302 to the keycloak login which then redirects back to the application redirect URI which is supposed to be able to get the access token.

At this point the angular-oauth2-oidc client fails to retrieve the token with the following error : "Validating access_token failed, wrong state/nonce. null M2RzWkNnaH5XeGRNM1MxU1BwRXdRUi1NZlBOWkZOekdJWUd1Y2VjX2ZCWlNo"

From what I debugged, I saw that the angular-oauth2-oidc attempts to validate the nonce from the session storage before calling Keycloak for the access token.

In this case the session storage where the library holds the data seems to be empty. My assumption is due to Keycloak reset password email link opening a new tab which redirects back to the angular app in a different tab from the initial one where the process was started and the session storage is no longer available.

This does not happen in the normal login flow as the nonce is present in the session storage when we are being redirected back to the angular app from the login page of Keycloak, thus the nonce check does not fail and the token can be retrieved.

If I switch the angular-oauth2-oidc to store the data in the localStorage everything works as expected and there is no error when resetting the password/validating the email.

As far as I read setting the storage to localStorage is not a good idea due to security concerns.

General info about the setup :

- Keycloak runs in a docker container with the latest image/tag (quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest)
- Angular version 15 with the latest version of angular-oauth2-oidc
- Keycloak is configured with basic settings to enable auth+pkse + forgot password enabled.
- The overall integration works, login, token retrieval etc is all set up and running correctly, except when emails are involved(verify + password reset)

Did I miss anything in the documentation or in the configuration? My expectation was that this flow would work out of the box just by turning on the verify and forgot password settings in Keycloak.

Thank you !

I tried :

- Setting the localstorage as a the library storage. Works, but not
  secure ?
- Debugging the client library. I found the issue, but no solution.
- I searched for other related questions, such as
  [OAuth2 code flow with angular-oauth2-oidc and Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72458568/oauth2-code-flowwith-angular-oauth2-oidc-and-keycloak)
- Based on https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/issues/728 we can write a custom oAuthStorage that keeps the nonce and code verifier in the localstorage instead of the session storage. Would that be a good approach in terms of security?